# Using leaf-off LiDAR for canopy density and canopy height

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, canopy-height-model

Could someone explain the drawbacks of using leaf-off LiDAR data to calculate canopy density and height? Is it acceptable to use this at all?

I have read a few papers but I find it hard to make complete sense of them. Some say that leaf-off is ok and others say it is not, and others say to combine on and off for the best results.

Only leaf-off is available in my study area.

Comment: Have you tried the leaf-off data?  If so, what were the results?  I've only worked with leaf-on data, so no personal experience with leaf-off.  However, I suspect that leaf-on would provide more definitive canopy height results, if for no other reason than it has more canopy reflective surface area.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283318/how-much-do-leaves-on-off-affect-the-number-of-lidar-ground-returns

Comment: Related: https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0303243420300684?token=728E38794562EFCDDF6566ABF5F61C12F38405ED141F96E238961DD9CD3C96D3A7529A4C308308BC902E7D42E5B3D15D&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20211013165626

Answer (score 2):

During leaf-off conditions, canopy height will likely be underestimated (the height of points is shifted downwards) as laser pulses tends to penetrate deeper into the canopy before triggering a return (backscatter) signal. The magnitude of this effect will vary depending on the diameter of the laser footprint as it hits the forest canopy (a function of sensor altitude and beam divergence). For example, sensors with small laser footprints (e.g., UAV lidar) may record fewer points at the top of the canopy as laser pulses travel deeper into the canopy before triggering a return signal. Conversely, sensors with wider footprints (e.g., satellite lidar) are less sensitive to this effect as there is a greater probability that the laser pulse will intercept the top of canopy.

Canopy density will be reduced during leaf-off conditions since there is less biological material to intercept the laser pulses. This will also influence the estimation of canopy cover.

Most lidar data is collected during leaf-off conditions because the primary interest is terrain mapping (for applications such as flood mapping) rather than forest mensuration. The data can still be useful if:

- you are only analysing measurements taken during leaf-off conditions.
- you want to quantify leaf biomass by comparing leaf-on versus leaf-off measurements.

However, if you are trying to estimate parameters such as timber volume or carbon content, then I would hesitate to ***compare*** leaf-off with leaf-on data. The variations in height and density will likely introduce bias to the retrieval of timber volume and carbon content as these parameters are estimated through regression analysis.